Why is an LLC converter's optimal Lm Lr ratio around 10?
I have seen this ratio of 9 to 11 being close to optimal for the Lm to Lr ratio in LLC resonant converters.
Aall the sources mostly state it as a matter of fact instead of explaining why.
What is the reason?

Besides the Lm:Lr ratio's electrical influence, which is described in the other answer, there are also a lot of trade-offs to be made with regards to the magnetic design, which I'll detail in this answer.
There's no such thing as an optimal resonant to magnetizing inductance factor in an LLC resonant converter. Every choice you make has significant drawbacks, and your goal as a designer is to find a transformer design whose drawbacks you can live with. Getting to a design that works well is hard, and no matter what you do, you'll likely not be happy with it in the end.
Most (if not all) commercial LLC resonant SMPS designs use a single transformer that does double duty as the resonant inductor via its leakage inductance. In this common case, the Lm:Lr ratio boils down to the transformer's coupling factor (in particular, 1/k - 1). This has implications for the physical construction of the transformer.
In a resonant converter, you usually want a fair amount of resonant inductance (especially at high input voltages) to keep the impedance of the LC tank circuit within reasonable limits. To achieve this, you need to add leakage inductance to your transformer if you want to avoid adding an external inductor. There are two ways to go about this: You can add more turns (increasing both Lm and Lr) or decrease the coupling factor k (increasing Lr only). In practice, you'll combine both approaches.
If you add more turns, you'll quickly find yourself running into a different problem: Winding resistance and skin effect. As you add turns, you either need to make the wire thinner to fit it on the transformer, or you choose a bigger transformer core and use the additional space to add more copper. Thinner wire means more resistance, and therefore lower efficiency. So you choose a bigger transformer and add more copper to combat this. More copper means less resistance and better efficiency, right? Unfortunately not. As your winding layers get deeper, the skin effect forces current to flow only in a small fraction of the conductor's cross-sectional area, thereby making it as if you had just chosen a thinner wire to begin with - raising the resistance of the winding.
Of course, you could also just keep both the resonant inductance and capacitance low. Doing so increases the converter's full-load operating frequency, which leads to higher switching losses, and also higher conduction losses due to the skin effect again... Oops. Better not increase the switching frequency too much, then.
So at a given frequency and power level, there's a limit to how many turns you can easily put on a transformer due to the skin effect. This prevents you from simply adding more turns to increase inductance.
You still need that resonant inductance to hit your desired capacitor size and resonant frequency, though... The other thing you can do is to lower k. Doing so "splits" the total inductance of the transformer in a different way, giving you proportionally more leakage inductance.
Counter-intuitively, making a very bad transformer (with low k) is actually rather difficult. At the most basic level, you can use a split-bobbin construction style, which allows you to use the volume within the transformer's windings as an air-core inductor. This is nice and simple, but with typical E- or RM-style cores, you'll quickly run into a limit at around k=0.9 (giving you Lm:Lr of about 10). Spacing the windings further apart and increasing the size of the air gap might get you to k=0.8 or so with some effort. If you want even more resonant inductance, you need to resort to more exotic techniques like adding magnetic shunts. Unfortunately, shunts increase the magnetic flux density in the core material, thereby increasing core losses.
As you go down this path of magnetic madness, you'll quickly find yourself doing magnetic field simulations with finite element analysis because all of the closed-form rule-of-thumb formulas will have broken down and become useless at that point.
To summarize:

At low Lm:Lr (5 or less, high leakage inductance), you run into the problems of transformer manufacturability, core loss, and high quiescent resonant current that leads to bad low-load efficiency. You also get high capacitor voltage stress (due to lower capacitance).
At high Lm:Lr (15 or more, low leakage inductance), you instead get limited control range (poor tolerance to input voltage variations), high operating frequency variation, and bad high-load efficiency (due to conduction losses from skin effect). You also need larger capacitors.
Somewhere in-between, you can combine all of those disadvantages in a way that might just barely be acceptable for your design.

As it turns out, for most real-world designs, manufacturability and core loss problems get unacceptably bad below a ratio of about 5. Similarly, the other problems become unacceptable above a ratio of 15 or so.
In the end, you'll likely take whatever Lm:Lr ratio actually works without excessive losses and is manufacturable, and not the one you initially decided to use.

In a resonant converter, you usually want a fair amount of resonant inductance (especially at high input voltages) in order to keep the resonant capacitors small because caps are expensive <-- smaller capacitance values means the peak resonating voltage can sky-rocket and so, there is a good case for exactly the opposite of this statement. I'm saying this so that you can consider improving your answer.

@Andyaka Note that applies for no-load conditions, with no functional regulation; a closed loop controller can't operate in that region. Also, modern controllers monitor Cr (usually by voltage directly, then also inferring inverter current from that), even incorporating it into the control loop (e.g. TI's "hybrid hysteretic" control), further avoiding such operation. The main motivation, at least AFAIK, is to get Lr/Cr in such range that maximum power can be delivered at minimum Vin.

I'm talking about high/full loading conditions using phase shifted PWM.

Yeah, with load applied, the AC voltage across the capacitor is determined pretty much entirely by the frequency, output current, and capacitance. (All of the transformed output current flows through that cap in AC form.) So there is indeed a minimum capacitance value for a certain operating frequency, current, and cap voltage rating. I've edited the answer so that it no longer implies that less capacitance is always better.

I have started looking into resonant converters in the 2000's, when high-power flat panel displays were heavy consumers of these structures. I remember attending a course taught by the late Dr. Milan Jovanovic (accent on the c) on LLC conversion. During this class, he covered several design examples and compared  three different values of \$L_m\$, \$L_s\$ and \$C_s\$ by computing voltage and current stress, but also frequency variations for the same regulation goal:

The six combinations were then gathered in an array, showing the primary-side rms current and the peak voltage across the resonant capacitor:

According to the simulations, design number 6 with a ratio of 6 between \$L_m\$ and \$L_s\$ was the best tradeoff for the considered variables the author wanted to keep low, including acceptable frequency variations across the load range.
On top of these experiments, I have added the control-to-output transfer functions of these 6 LLC designs, showing how the different combinations affect the ac response. This is direct frequency control and simulations are carried with SIMPLIS, using the simplified model you can find in my free ready-made templates:

The output voltage in kept constant by the simple low-gain Zener-based regulator and the input voltage is set at 390 V dc. Once you assemble all the transfer functions, you have the below graph:

You can clearly see how the various components selections affect the ac response. For #6 and #4, you have a peaky magnitude, with a phase stress at 2 kHz while the other combinations lead to a rather low-\$Q\$ type of second-order behavior. That is the difficulty with the LLC converter, depending on the operating point (switching frequency versus resonant frequency) and the components values, you may have different ac responses, leading to more or less complicated compensation schemes with a type 2 or 3 compensators.
You will certainly improve the situation by departing from direct frequency control and adopting different control schemes such as those described in my seminar on LLC control methods.

Full bridge, phase shift, fixed frequency, with current mode control is in fact what i am developing. I dont know if the Lm / Lr ratio matters as much in fixed frequency operation like that as long as the gain curves are ~1 for all the loads and the magnetizing currents do not affect the efficiency too much since i do not need varying gain with increasing frequency in order to regulate the output voltage.

I would say the PSFB is still a buck-derived topology with its output inductor. The presence of the extra inductor $L_r$ in the primary side tends to damp the 2nd-order response in VM (no peaking) and CM should be smoother (I did not cover it in my large-signal model here) but did in my book on TF.

Well the optimum Lm/Lr ratio is application dependent. Big for high efficiency, but small for good control range. Some literature states 6, others say 5 to 11. If integrated magnetics is desired which is often the case with low power then going on the high side will make transformer losses lower and its construction less exotic.

Would you say this is more relevant for frequency controlled rather than fixed frequency converters ?

@Stonie All LLC resonant converters are frequency-controlled.

@JonathanS. if by that you mean they all use frequency as a variable to achieve the design aims then that is not the case because there are fixed frequency LLC resonant converters.

@Andyaka You're right, that's a fair point. I've added an answer that goes into points that also apply for fixed-frequency variations of the topology.

If you gents are interested, I covered control methods for LLC converters in a recent presentation. I did not include the more recent hysteretic regulation scheme from TI which is truly close to bang-bang charge control from Queens University.

There's no such optimal Lm/Lr ratio.
It's application-dependent, and also depends on how you define the "optimal" or what you understand from it (*).
It's sometimes a misunderstood parameter because Lm/Lr is not an individual design parameter that you can randomly choose. Instead, you choose Lm/Lm ratio, NPS (transformer turns ratio) and Q (quality factor) at the same time to ensure ZVS (zero-voltage switching) across the entire input and loading range. Changing one of these may result in a re-selection of at least one of the other two.
Here are some examples:

If you want the converter's operating point to go towards "above resonance" even for the nominal input voltage then you should decrease the turns ratio. S you may need to re-select Lm/Lm ratio and Q because your previous selection may not be applicable as they may not meet the gain requirements.

If you want a narrower operating frequency range across the entire loading conditions for better EMI then you'll probably end up with higher Q factor. In this case the tank may not meet the gain requirements so you may need to decrease Lm/Lr ratio.

At lower input voltages and higher loading conditions the switching frequency will decrease and the operation point will approach to the capacitive region further. At the region where the gain curve becomes steep stability may not be easier to achieve especially if you are working with an VCO(voltage-controlled oscillator)-based controller.


So no, there's no such single (or a range of) optimal Lm/Lr ratio. You select or calculate one along with other tank parameters, and see if it works.
(*) On my recent wide-input (250 ~ 420 VDC) converter design I ended up with an Lm/Lr ratio of less than 4 which is way below that so-called optimal ratio.
